# Access an array of pointers to objects on device CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

New to CUDA and gpu programming, having trouble with copying array of object pointers to device.

I have a vector of object pointers, each object contains two vectors, that I will be working with in device code.

I need to somehow copy that array into the device memory, however after reading similar solutions, still can't figure it out.

This is the structure of an object, I'm working with:

```
   std::vector<int> retVals;
   std::vector<int> children{4};
```

So, not only I need to make copy of the array, I also need to convert these vectors to the int array in each object.

**EDIT:**

This is what I have come up so far with:

```
auto **nodesPtr = ( aho_corasick::Node**)malloc(a->nodes.size() * sizeof(aho_corasick::Node *));

    int i = 0;
    for (auto &node: a->nodes){
        auto *newNode = new aho_corasick::Node(' ');

        cudaMalloc((void**)&(newNode->cudaChildren), sizeof(int) * node->children.size());
        cudaMemcpy(newNode->cudaChildren, node->children.data(), sizeof(int) * node->children.size(), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMalloc((void**)&(newNode->cudaRets), sizeof(int) * node->retVals.size());
        cudaMemcpy(newNode->cudaRets, node->children.data(), sizeof(int) * node->retVals.size(), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        aho_corasick::Node* devNode;

        cudaMalloc((void**)&devNode, sizeof(aho_corasick::Node));
        cudaMemcpy(devNode, newNode, sizeof(aho_corasick::Node), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        nodesPtr[i++] = devNode;
    }

    aho_corasick::Node **devNodes;

    cudaMalloc((void **)&devNodes, a->nodes.size() * sizeof(aho_corasick::Node *));
    cudaMemcpy(devNodes, nodesPtr, a->nodes.size() * sizeof(aho_corasick::Node *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Still does not seem to work tho.

Also, how bad is such code in CUDA terms and how would I go around the array of pointers?

**EDIT2**:

Forgot to point out: I added two additional fields in my objects: two int arrays and in the for loop I am creating a new object, into which I am copying the two corresponding vectors (into the int array fields) and after that I am creating a new object in device memory with those fields.

Then, after the loop, I am allocating the array of object pointers in device memory.

Comment: Your second `cudaMemcpy` copies from the wrong location. `&devNodes` is a triple pointer not a double pointer. That may not fix everything but should be a start.

Comment: Thank you, @Shadow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  auto **nodesPtr = (aho_corasick::Node **) malloc(a->nodes.size() * sizeof(aho_corasick::Node *));

    int i = 0;

    for (auto &node: a->nodes) {

        auto *newNode = new aho_corasick::Node(' ');

        cudaMalloc((void **) &(newNode->cudaChildren), sizeof(int) * node->children.size());
        cudaMemcpy(newNode->cudaChildren, node->children.data(), sizeof(int) * node->children.size(),
                   cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMalloc((void **) &(newNode->cudaRets), sizeof(int) * node->retVals.size());
        cudaMemcpy(newNode->cudaRets, node->retVals.data(), sizeof(int) * node->retVals.size(),
                   cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        newNode->retsCount = node->retVals.size();

        aho_corasick::Node *devNode;

        cudaMalloc((void **) &devNode, sizeof(aho_corasick::Node));
        cudaMemcpy(devNode, newNode, sizeof(aho_corasick::Node), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        nodesPtr[i++] = devNode;
    }


    aho_corasick::Node **devNodes;

    cudaMalloc((void ***) &devNodes, a->nodes.size() * sizeof(aho_corasick::Node *));
    cudaMemcpy(devNodes, nodesPtr, a->nodes.size() * sizeof(aho_corasick::Node *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

This is how I copied my array of object into device. However, as it turns out, for my task this approach is not acceptable. It takes few hours to copy all objects.

Closing this thread, but if someone knows how to avoid using array of pointers and therefore avoid copying, please let me know.